# Populating a column in a data-frame based on multiple conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

I have this dataframe which has 3 columns specifications, publish_date and price. The replicating code is added:

```
x=as.data.frame(c("3/4inches|20x20|4.56",
"3/4inches|20x21|5.56","3/4inches|20x22|7.11"))
x1=do.call("rbind",replicate(3,x,simplify = F))
colnames(x1)="specification"

sd=as.data.frame(seq(as.Date("2017-08-01"),as.Date("2017-08-03"),by = "day"))
sd=sd[rep(seq_len(nrow(sd)), each=3),]
sd=data.frame(sd)
colnames(sd)="publish_date"

price=data.frame(c(12.34,12.54,""))
price=do.call("rbind",replicate(3,price,simplify = F))
colnames(price)="price"

df.sample=cbind(sd,x1,price)
df.sample
publish_date        specification price
1   2017-08-01 3/4inches|20x20|4.56 12.34
2   2017-08-01 3/4inches|20x21|5.56 12.54
3   2017-08-01 3/4inches|20x22|7.11      
4   2017-08-02 3/4inches|20x20|4.56 12.34
5   2017-08-02 3/4inches|20x21|5.56 12.54
6   2017-08-02 3/4inches|20x22|7.11      
7   2017-08-03 3/4inches|20x20|4.56 12.34
8   2017-08-03 3/4inches|20x21|5.56 12.54
9   2017-08-03 3/4inches|20x22|7.11
```

Suppose, the price for the date "2017-08-01" and specification "3/4inches|20x22|7.11" is 16.14, then for the next date the price should appear as 16.14 for the same specification.

```
publish_date        specification price
    1   2017-08-01 3/4inches|20x20|4.56 12.34
    2   2017-08-01 3/4inches|20x21|5.56 12.54
    3   2017-08-01 **3/4inches|20x22|7.11** **16.14**     
    4   2017-08-02 3/4inches|20x20|4.56 12.34
    5   2017-08-02 3/4inches|20x21|5.56 12.54
    6   2017-08-02 3/4inches|20x22|7.11 **16.14**    
    7   2017-08-03 3/4inches|20x20|4.56 12.34
    8   2017-08-03 3/4inches|20x21|5.56 12.54
    9   2017-08-03 3/4inches|20x22|7.11 **16.14**
```

Hence, to summarize the query: for the dates when the price is missing I need to check the previous days date, then match the specification and then pull the price from previous date to the current date.

Thanks in advance! The actual data has location checks along with 35678 days,67 specifications.Hence the inputs would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, where does the `16.14` come from ? Since your sample is a replicate, it does not explain well your question's limit cases.

Comment: @DanChaltiel, 16.14 was a added just to explain the example. I would try to explain the problem, i.e. I have to populate the price column(if empty) based on the specification present on immediate previous date. The price column has missing values. Hence based on the same specification for the previous date, the price needs to be fetched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly you only look to previous values for the same specification?
The it's easiest to split your data.frame first into the seperate cases, then we only need to look upward.

There's the function `na.locf` from the `zoo`-package, that does almost exactly what you need: it replaces any `NA`'s with the last non-`NA` value. Here I'm only assuming your data.frame is ordered by date.
And finally I notice you're using an empty string to denote missing values, generally you want to use `NA` for that. And `na.locf` only works on `NA`'s, so I replaced the empty strings as a first step

```
install.packages('zoo') # If you don't have it yet
df.sample$price[df.sample$price==""] <- NA
spl <- split(df.sample, df.sample$specification)
spl <- lapply(spl, zoo::na.locf, na.rm=FALSE)
df.sample <- unsplit(spl, df.sample$specification)
```

Only if you have products for which there is no previous price, those remain `NA`

Comment: Many thanks to you @EmilBode. I have been struggling with the same for few days and I sincerely appreciate it. Thanks again!

Comment: if I have to add multiple conditions while splitting then how to achieve in the following cmd: spl <- split(df.sample, c(df.sample$specification,df.sample$location)) gives error. Please help.